# 2013 - Error while searching with only with specific user

Tags: 2013, search, exception

I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2013, updated to the latest CU available (november 2016).

Two days ago I've fixed some search error that I've seen in ULS logs. I've re-created the index, then done a full crawl and finally enabled the incremental crawl. Everything worked fine.

But today I'm facing this problem: searching from different user cause that I see correct results from an user, but for the other one user I receive an error (database exception).

Last week I've upgraded from July 2015 CU to the latest CU. Should I re-run the product configuration wizard? Or do you have any other suggestion about my error?

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, after applying a SharePoint update, run the configuration wizard.  I had to learn this by getting Microsoft support on the phone.